# Testing with Rspec, NiftyAuthentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm using Ryan Bates's `nifty:authentication`, and starting testing with Rspec. Fought with this for weeks, and still don't understand what's happening.

My controller simply calls

```
before_filter :login_required, :except => [:login]
```

Which is defined in lib/controller_authentication

```
def self.included(controller)
    controller.send :helper_method, :current_account, :logged_in?, :redirect_to_target_or_default
  end

  def current_account
    @current_account ||= Account.find(session[:account_id]) if session[:account_id]
  end

  def logged_in?
    current_account
  end

  def login_required
    unless logged_in?
      store_target_location
      redirect_to login_url, :alert => "You must first answer me these riddles three log in or sign up before accessing this page."
    end
  end

  def redirect_to_target_or_default(default, *args)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default, *args)
    session[:return_to] = nil
  end

  private

  def store_target_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url
  end
end
```

The app works as intended, but the testing fails every time. No matter what I try, I get the `redirect_to login_url, :alert => "You must first ...log in"` page.

Things I've tried:

```
controller.stub!( :login_required )
ControllerAuthentication.stub!(:current_account).and_return(Account.where(:username => 'ej0c').first)
#ControllerAuthentication.stub!(:logged_in?).and_return(Account.where(:username => 'ej0c').first)
ControllerAuthentication.stub!(:login_required).and_return(true)
MyDigisController.stub!( :login_required ).and_return(true)
```

Which I think means I'm missing the whole theory of the thing. How can I make my login work?

---

I tried as Punit suggests below:
[pre]

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "View event details" do

  it "Should show a table of events" do
     @account = Account.where(:username => 'ej0c').first
     puts @account.inspect
     controller.stub!(:current_account).and_return(@account)
     controller.stub!(:logged_in?).and_return(true)
     session[:account_id] = @account.id
      visit '/my_digis/66/custom_events'
      page.should have_content('Events')

  end
end
```

@account.inspect displayed nicely, but I also got

```
An expectation of :current_account was set on nil. Called from C:/Users/Ed/webapps/whendidji3/spec/con
.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'. Use allow_message_expectations_on_nil to disable warn
An expectation of :logged_in? was set on nil. Called from C:/Users/Ed/webapps/whendidji3/spec/controll
:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'. Use allow_message_expectations_on_nil to disable warnings.
```

Thanks for any detailed explanations, as I've searched high an low to understand what's goin on.

Comment: can we get some code formatting? highlight your code and click the code button or manually move it over 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the answer was that I needed a request spec.

I'd begun with a request spec, but it wasn't in the `requests` folder, and the questions I asked got it morphed into a half-request/half-controller spec, none of which works.

The strange thing about rspec is that it will complain if a capybara method is badly formed,...but it won't mention that the thing just plain doesn't work where you put it!

My working spec, located in `specs/requests/my_digis_spec.rb` is

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "MyDigis" do

   before :each do
@account = Account.where(:username => 'me').first
visit login_path
    fill_in 'Username or Email Address', :with => @account.email
    fill_in 'Password', :with => 'password'
  click_button('Log in')
```

end

```
it "Shows list of digis" do
  visit my_digis_path
  page.should have_content('Your Custom Event groups')
end

it "Lets you modify didji list" do
  visit my_digis_path
  click_button('Modify events')
  page.should have_content('Events for my_digi')
end
```

end

As easy as advertised, just took me 5 weeks to get the login part. Thanks.

Comment: but that's not stubbing. Tests become much less modular with such an approach.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a vanilla spec rather than a controller spec, which means that the variable 'controller' is not being set.

To use a controller spec, you need to pass the controller class name to your describe block rather than a string.

```
describe MyController do
```

see http://rspec.info/rails/writing/controllers.html

Once you have that going, you should be able to use your original thought of stubbing login_required

Comment: thanks,that fixed the nil errors (I forgot about nested describes!) But the stub still seems to be ignored. The validation fails as before, returning the "You must first login" page.

Comment: OK, i've narrowed it down to the 'visit' method. If I switch to 'get :index' it works. Do webrat methods just not work here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to stub the "current_account" method. You could do it like this -

```
@account = create_account #function to create an account for your specs
controller.stub!(:current_account).and_return(@account)
controller.stub!(:logged_in?).and_return(true)
```

You should probably create a method out of the above lines to stub authentication wherever required.